# JavaFx WebEngine - Overwriting a website's stylesheet with (local) files

Tags: java, html, css, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'd like to customise the appearance of a website that I am loading, so I created a little `test.css` file that does nothing but changing the look of all table rows:

```
tr {
    height: 22px;
    background-image: url("test.png");
}
```

**How do I get he WebEngine to load this file and replace the page's own CSS rules with mine?**
Also, i'd like to be able to load **page-specific css files** and not one huge file for all pages.

---

I found [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/621184/JavaFX/java/apply-custom-css-rule-JavaFX), but it only shows how to run through the DOM and assign a new style to the desired elements by hand. This is, of course, not what I want. Instead, I'd like the browser to use my files as 'user defaults'.

Thx for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of I have to state, that I hope you know what you are doing, as these things can seriously damage a web site.
So here is what you can do:

You grab the `Document` from the `WebEngine`, retrieve the `head` element and add a `style` child element to it, containing the src location of the stylesheet you want to add.

```
Document doc = webView.getEngine().getDocument();
URL scriptUrl = getClass().getResource(pathToAttachedDocument); // pathToAttachedDocument = CSS file you want to attach
String content = IOUtils.toString(scriptUrl); // Use Apache IO commons for conveniance
Element appendContent = doc.createElement("style");
appendContent.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(content));
doc.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(appendContent);
```

By the way, JavaScript can be added in a similar way, it's just 'script' instead of 'style'

Comment: My mistake was to create a `link` element to reference the css file instead of `style`, but doing so after the page was completely loaded obviously couldn't work. Thanks a lot!

Just one more thing: **Where must i put the `test.png`?** I tried saving it in the same folder as the css file and in the project root folder. The reference only seems to work when linking it to an online URL.

Comment: The `test.png` as it is defined in your example should be in the same location as the CSS file that is loaded. You can also place it in a different folder and use a relative path to it in the CSS.

Comment: i tried putting the file in the same folder, but then nothing happened - the background was left blank. It only works when I copy the file to my webspace and load it from there (`background-image: url("http://www.blabla.com/test.png") !important;`) , but this is not the intended solution :O

Comment: Do you by any chance use JVM version 1.8.0_60?  I think with that version is an issue so that you have to reference your local resources in the HTML with `classpath:` prefix.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I do use verion 1.8.0_60. However, I don't know how to do what you suggested - sorry =/ Do I have to put `background-image: url("classpath:test.png") !important;` into my css file, or must I mess around with the `.classpath` file? (I use eclipse btw)

Comment: In our code, this: `<script type="text/javascript" src='classpath:/html/pciContainer.js'></script>` is what should end up in the HTML, For a CSS it is pretty similar. In the CSS you then should be able to reference the image as usual without the classpath.

Comment: By now I have tested your suggestion in every variation that I can think of. This is what my style tag looks like: `<STYLE type="text/css" src="classpath:/data/style/test.css">`. I tried without the `/` after `classpath:`, i tried with the css file's full url (with and without `file:/` prefix). Nothing worked :(
Is it possible that the `style` tag simply does not support the `src` attribute? If not: could there be a workaround? (I am not too fluent with all html tags)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this to ADD or REPLACE any rules :

```
String css  = getFileAsString("style.css");
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
Element e = doc.getElementById("my_style");
e.setTextContent(css);
```

... given a

```
<style id="my_style"></style>
```

tag in the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

[`setUserStyleSheetLocation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setUserStyleSheetLocation-java.lang.String-)was designed for that very purpose: to let the **user** of the web page, style it as they want.

Usage:

`webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(styleSheetURL.toString());`