# Customize JavaFX WebView scrollbar width

Tags: css, webview, javafx, scrollbar

Is there a way to adjust the thickness of the scrollbars of a WebView using the stylesheet used by the whole JavaFX application?

I am a bit confused since

- on the one hand I read that the scrollbars are not part of the JavaFX UI control and therefore can only be customized by a stylesheet set on the web engine (webview.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(..)) which means I have to write another CSS trying that the scrollbars look like all other scrollbars in the application
- and on the other hand I can see that the scrollbars are obviously correctly customized using the JavaFX CSS except the thickness of the scrollbars (and that the vertical scrollbar is always shown even if the loaded page requires no scrollbars at all)

So where am I wrong and which is the correct way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What page are you loading in your WebView? It might be that the style of the page defines something for its scrollbar, like `overflow-y: 'scroll'`.

Comment: I loaded different pages and yes, if the vertical scrollbar is always shown or not, seems to be a definition of these pages.

Comment: In that case your only option would be to override the style that the page provides itself. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751342/javafx-webengine-overwriting-a-websites-stylesheet-with-local-files

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I read and tried the approaches and it seemed to me that this results in the same than using webview.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(..) with a none-JavaFX stylesheet.

Comment: Can you explain why it looks as if the JavaFX styles are applied to the scrollbars of the webview to some degree?

Comment: Can you post the CSS styles of the web page as well as the ones for your webview?